# rank aggregation with partial ranking lists

Tags: ranking, aggregation, ranks

My question is about rank aggregation, which is in relation with statistics and decision sciences. (if this question is off the topic of this site, plz let me know.) The question is that I have N candidates and N ranking lists in which each candidate is omitted, that is, candidate 1's rank is omitted in the 1st ranking list. And my task is to aggregate all those ranking lists to one.

| Candidate | ranking1 | ranking2 | ranking3 | ranking4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A |  | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 1 |  | 2 | 3 |
| C | 3 | 2 |  | 2 |
| D | 2 | 3 | 3 |  |

I've read about some aggregation methods but here's my idea (or question). What if I want to assign more relative importance to the ranking lists whose vanishing candidate ranks relatively high after the first aggregation, to put it easily, that is, giving more weights to ranking lists without 1st rank candidate and so on. As in the table above, by simple average, the first ranking result would be A>B>C>D. Since A is ranked 1st, then ranking1 deserves (?) more importance and this could possibly lead to D>C in the second round. I'm not sure if this is reasonable and I have mentioned 'first' aggregation but I further go back to the second aggregation process based on the first aggregation result and what if they are inconsistent or if they are identical what does it infer?

Comment: Why are rankings omitted? Can you tell us a bit more about the design?

Comment: @Galen, just removing an alternative in each ranking round, the motivation is to see whether the overall one ranking will be different compared to the aggregation ranking results or under what circumstances.